# Android in ART garbage collection pause time indicates main thread or worker thread?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-runtime, pause

Does anybody know whether GC log below, "paused 1.439ms", means pause time on background thread that CMS is working on, or pause time on main thread?

I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 266189(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 46MB/54MB, paused 1.439ms total 179.694m

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug.html

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. However, those posts do not mention whether the pause is the pause in main thread or worker thread

Comment: Did you check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620473/android-in-art-garbage-collection-pause-time-indicates-main-thread-or-worker-thr/35790729#35790729)?

Comment: @RohitArya Hey Rohit, sorry for the late check up.
So, are you saying that pause time are 
foreground call -- main thread pause time
background call -- background thread pause time?

But, even if you do the background GC, at first, you need to mark the lived heap resources, which is STOP THE WORLD operation.
I wonder if the pause time showing on the log includes the first mark operation..

Comment: @KyungminLee, yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kind of GC pauses in ART:

1) In the log below *Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC* indicates **foreground** call.

```
I/art(801): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65595(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(4MB) LOS objects, 810% free, 38MB/58MB, paused 1.195ms total 87.219ms
```

2) In the logs below *Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC* and *Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC* indicate **background** call.

```
I/art(29197): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 74626(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 39(4MB) LOS objects, 1496% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 4.422ms total 1.371747s

I/art(29197): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 70319(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 59(5MB) LOS objects, 825% free, 49MB/56MB, paused 6.139ms total 52.868ms
```

Hope this helps you out!